# if statement of button found

Tags: javascript, imacros

My goal is, if a page contains the specified button, click it, and increase the `amt_clicked` by 1. When `amt_clicked` is greater than 15, wait for 60 seconds and reset `amt_clicked`. I have no idea how do this if statement. Example:

```
var amt_clicked = 0;
while (1) {
    while (amt_clicked < 15) {

        if (button found) { // this is where I am lost
            iimPlay("TAG POS={{amt_clicked}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Get");
            amt_clicked++;
        }
    }

    iimPlay("WAIT SECONDS=60");
    amt_clicked = 0;
}
```

Comment: @Rajesh markup? This is for imacros

Comment: That's an infinite loop. I recommend `setInterval()`.

Comment: What is button found returning here. Is it true or false?

Comment: @SaugatBhattarai I don't know. I am using imacro (firefox extension) for this, so I don't know if it returns anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

This will run 20 times per second, using the `window.setInterval()` function:

```
var amt_clicked = 0;
var amt_cooldown = 1200;
setInterval(function(){
    if (amt_cooldown === 0)
        amt_cooldown = 1200;
    else if (amt_cooldown < 1200)
        amt_cooldown -= 1;
    else if (amt_clicked > 15) {
        amt_clicked = 1;
        amt_cooldown -= 1;
    } else {
        amt_clicked -= 1;
        //Click
}, 50);
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I wanted. I edited my code. Its just 1 line I am lost on

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).
I have added comments to code for you to understand.

```js
var amt_clicked = 0;
var setTimeoutInProcess = false;

//processing the interval click function
setInterval(() => {
  checkButtonAgain();
}, 200);


function checkButtonAgain() {

  var element = document.getElementById('iNeedtoBeClicked');

  //if clicked 15 times then need to wait for 60 seconds
  if (amt_clicked === 15) {
    if (!setTimeoutInProcess) {
      setTimeoutInProcess = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
        //resetting the amt-clicked
        amt_clicked = 0;
        setTimeoutInProcess = false;
      }, 60000);
    } else {
      console.log('waiting');
    }
  } else if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null) {
    //triggering click and increasing the amt_clicked
    element.click();
    amt_clicked++;
  }
  console.log(amt_clicked);
}
```

```html
<button id="iNeedtoBeClicked">Click ME Button</button>
```